# How to extract the substring of a string by "not" select?

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a weird date column written as

1012003 for 1/01/2003,
8132003 for 8/13/2003
6082003 for 6/08/2003
12172003 for 12/17/2003
Using

```
stri_sub(df$date,-4)
```

I get the year or last 4 digits

Using

```
stri_sub(df$date,-6,-5)
```

I get the date. How would i get the month?

I would like to do something that selects what remains based on the selecting the 6 most to the right.

I thought something like this might work

```
  stri_sub(!df$date,-6)
```

I would like to be left with 1,8,6, and 12.

Comment: Just extract the digita before the first /. Or, alternatively, extract the first two symbols and if the second one is a /, place it by ““.

Comment: there are no lines. its just written like this "1012003" not "10/12/200"

Comment: True. Sorry, I misread your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
> x <- c('1012003', '8132003', '6082003', '12172003')
> substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 6)
[1] "1"  "8"  "6"  "12"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a leading zero, convert to real dates, and then do whatever you want with them...

```
v <- c(1012003, 8132003, 6082003 , 12172003)

# Add leading zero if needed
new.v <- sprintf("%08d", v)
#[1] "01012003" "08132003" "06082003" "12172003"

# Convert to date
v.dates <- as.Date(new.v, format = "%m%d%Y")
#[1] "2003-01-01" "2003-08-13" "2003-06-08" "2003-12-17"

# extract month-numbers
lubridate::month(v.dates)
#[1]  1  8  6 12
```

Answer (score 0):

We could expand `substr()` a little.

```
substr2 <- Vectorize(function(x, start, stop) {
  stopifnot(sign(start) + sign(stop) != 0)
  rv <- function(i) Reduce(paste0, rev(el(strsplit(i, ''))))
  if (start < 0) {
    rv(substr(rv(x), -start, -stop))
  } else {
    substr(x, start, stop)
  }
}, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

### Usage

```
substr2(z, -1, -4)  ## years
# [1] "2003" "2003" "2003" "2003"

substr2(z, -5, -6)  ## days
# [1] "01" "13" "08" "17"

substr2(z, -7, -8)  ## months
# [1] "1"  "8"  "6"  "12"
```

---

*Data:*

```
z <- c('1012003', '8132003', '6082003', '12172003')
```